# Big query insert /delete to table

Tags: python, sql, json, google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

I have a table X in big query with 170,000 rows . The values on this table as based on complex calculations done on the values from a table Y. These are done in python so as to automate the ingestion when Y gets updated.

Every time Y updates, I recompute the values needed for X in my script and insert them using the script below using streaming:

```
def stream_data(table, json_data):

  data = json.loads(str(json_data))
  # Reload the table to get the schema.
  table.reload()

  rows = [data]
  errors = table.insert_data(rows)

  if not errors:
    print('Loaded 1 row into {}'.format( table))
  else:
    print('Errors:')
```

The problem here is that I have to delete all rows in the table before I insert . I know  a query to do this but it fails because big query does not allow DML when there is a streaming buffer on the table and this is for one day apparently.

IS there a workaround where I can delete all rows in X , recompute based on Y and then insert the new values using the code above ??
Possibly turning the streaming buffer off ??!!

Another option would be to drop the whole table and recreate it . But my table is huge with 60 columns and the JSON for the schema would be huge . I couldn't find samples where I can create a new table with schema passed from json/file ? Some samples in this would be great.

A third option is to make the streaming insert smart that it does an update instead of insert if the row has changed . This again is a DML operation and goes back to original problem.

**UPDATE:**
another approach I tried is to delete the table and recreate it . Before delete I copy the schema so I can set it in the new table.:

```
def stream_data( json_data):
    bigquery_client = bigquery.Client("myproject")
    dataset = bigquery_client.dataset("mydataset")
    table = dataset.table("test")
    data = json.loads(json_data)
    schema=table.schema

    table.delete()

    table = dataset.table("test")

    # Set the table schema
    table = dataset.table("test",schema)
    table.create()

    rows = [data]
    errors = table.insert_data(rows)

    if not errors:
        print('Loaded 1 row ')
    else:
        print('Errors:')
```

This gives me an error :
ValueError: Set either 'view_query' or 'schema'.

UPDATE 2:
Key was to do a
table.reload() before
schema=table.schema to fix the above!

Comment: have you tried overwriting the table (there's a flag in gsdk)